# Why isn't my function working in Parse Cloud Code? It works when I test in Angular and Express

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Why is my code not progressing? I tested it in both Angular and Express and the code progressed limited only by the inability to edit the User table with new data because the Master Key is necessary. Where am I going wrong?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("someFunction", function(request, response) {

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var user = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
var Table1 = Parse.Object.extend("Table1");
var table1Query = new Parse.Query(Table1);
var Table2 = Parse.Object.extend("Table2");
var table2Query = new Parse.Query(Table2);

var Ids = request.params.data; //this is an array of Parse.Object Ids

var array = [];

var x = Ids.length;

while (x--){
var Id = Ids[x];
console.log("This is active");//I know this working
table1Query.equalTo("user", {__type: "Pointer", className: "_User",                                                                              
                             objectId: Id});
table1Query.find({
success: function (results) {
         var resultIds = _.map(results, function (n) {
                           return n.id});

         var resultObjs = _.map(results, function (n) {
                           return return _.extend(_.find(n), {id: n.id})});

var a = resultIds.length;
while (a--) {
var resultId = resultIds[a];
console.log("I don't know why this is not coming up!?!");//Why isn't this working?
table2Query.equalTo("user", {__type: "Pointer", className: "_User",                                                                              
                             objectId: resultId});
table2Query.find({
success: function (items) {
var MA = _.map(_.flatten(items), function (n) {
return _.find(n)});

var step3 = _.map(resultObjs, function (n) {return _.extend(n, {
Matched: _.filter(MA, function (a) {return a.result.id == n.id})})});

var total = Math.round(_.reduce(_.map(step3, function (n) {return n.Bill
}), function (memo, num) {return memo + num;}, 0) * 100) / 100;

var duty = function (total, id) {
var promise = new Parse.Promise();
table2Query.get(id, {
success: function (Answer) {
Answer.set("duty", total);
Answer.save().then(function (difresult) {
response.success(difresult);
}, function (error) {
response.error(error);})
}
});
}
    array.push(duty(Answer, Id));
    }
})
}
}
})
}
return 

Parse.Promise.when(array).then(function() {
    response.success("Successfully retrieved Total Bills.");
},
    function(error) {
        response.error("Something is still wrong");
        console.log(error);
    });;
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's fix some coding errors first before I can continue.

Add ';' at the end of the below code.

```
 var Ids = req.params.data
 var x = Ids.length
 var a = resultIds.length
 array.push(duty(Answer, Id))
```

Then change **req** to **request**

```
 var Ids = req.params.data
```

to

```
 var Ids = request.params.data
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the suggested changes. Still, the code does not run.  I've come to the conclusion that Cloud Code does not like loops in general and that it's likely underscore must be used to asynchronousness.  Am I on the right track with this theory?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Are you sure the code is working? I found many other mistakes with your provided code.

Comment: I started a new question with my latest code and a slightly different question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499180/cloud-code-function-not-saving-data  thanks for taking a look!